# Create sitemap.xml.gz with PHP

Tags: php, sitemap

I have a problem with compressing sitemap.xml.gz. I use this code:

```
// Name of the file we're compressing
$file = '/path/'.'sitemap-'.$i.'.xml';

// Name of the gz file we're creating
$gzfile = 'sitemap-'.$i.'.xml'.".gz";

// Open the gz file (w9 is the highest compression)
$fp = gzopen ($gzfile, 'w9');

// Compress the file
gzwrite ($fp, file_get_contents($file));

// Close the gz file and we're done
gzclose($fp);
```

When I click on link example: www.example.com/sitemap/sitemap-1.xml.gz and when I open it, I get this: [IMAGE](http://s17.postimg.org/mfl920nsf/Untitled_2.jpg). If I wrote only www.example.com/sitemap/sitemap-1.gz I get correct file.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: The problem: when i want download sitemap.xml.gz from sitemapindex i get broken sitemap.xml ( these file is in sitemap.xml.gz ) You can tray it here: http://users.volja.net/evjkab704/sitemap-1.xml.gz

Comment: You're gzipping a file twice. So it's not "broken". I successfully opened an xml file from your archive.

Comment: Thanke you. But how can i fix it? Any opinion? My full code finde here: http://users.volja.net/evjkab704/t.txt

Comment: well, just don't compress it twice. If that is your actual code - then the original `xml` file is **already gzipped**.

Comment: My full code is here: users.volja.net/evjkab704/t.txt

Comment: Ok now it's workign. Error: .htaccess :) thank you for your help.